# MATLAB: alphashape with gaps?

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble to generate a "gap-free" alpha shape for the following example:

```
% surface points from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655393
aminor = 1.; % Torus minor radius
Rmajor = 3.; % Torus major radius
sd = 24;
theta  = linspace(-pi, pi, sd)   ; % Poloidal angle
phi    = linspace(0., 2.*pi, 2*sd) ; % Toroidal angle
[t, p] = meshgrid(phi, theta);
x = (Rmajor + aminor.*cos(p)) .* cos(t);
y = (Rmajor + aminor.*cos(p)) .* sin(t);
z = aminor.*sin(p);
```

I am creating the alpha shape with

```
alpha = 1;
shp = alphaShape(x(:),y(:),z(:), alpha);
plot(shp);
```

As you can see, alpha should be big enough to cover all distances between the desired surface points, yet the returned alpha shape contains some gaps.

What am I missing?

the torus as it should be:
[image: torus as it should be]

result from `alphaShape`
[image: alphashape with gaps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your alpha radius ends up being *exactly equal* to (or within some tolerance of) some of your surface points, but it needs to be *bigger* so that it encloses them. It works for me with `alpha = 1.1;`:

[image]

Note this from the [documentation for the alpha radius argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html#inputarg_a) (emphasis mine):

> The default alpha radius is `a = criticalAlpha(shp,'all-points')`, which is the smallest alpha radius that produces an alpha shape that **encloses all points**.

Comment: I am pretty sure that alpha is big enough to cover the distance between all adjacent points. there is also no regular pattern on the gaps which would indicate a relation to the node-distance.

Comment: There *is* a general pattern to the gaps: they occur more frequently at extrema (outer-most vertices, upper and lower vertices, vertices where the tube ends join). Note another excerpt, this time for the [`'Alpha'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html#inputarg_a) property: "The alpha radius is the radius of the alpha disk or sphere that sweeps over the points to create the alpha shape." In this case, alpha is the radius of the sphere that needs to enclose an entire slice of the toroid to join the points into one contiguous strip.

Comment: ... yeah, and I wasn't aware of the the proper definition of this `alpha` value. Now the gaps totally make sense (given the minor radius of the torus with `1.0`).