# How to plan path from point 1 to point 2 so that it remains in the specified region?

Tags: matlab, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pathgeometry

Basically this is a trajectory planning problem. As shown in figure below, how can I ensure that in moving from a point (x,y,z) to another point within torus, I don't get out of that torus region?(the region outside torus is not permissible for end effector of robot)[image: Go from (1)--->(2) without getting out of torus]

Comment: What have you done so far?  Where has your current attempt bogged down?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I have solved the forward and inverse kinematics (I'll upload the figures in a while) , if I give initial point on far left and destination point on far right, currently it moves on a straight trajectory. I actually don't know what to do so that the "via points" remain within torus

Comment: Interesting. I really appreciated the diagram.  I think you're more likely to get help if you [edit] your question to include your code, relevant plots or figures, etc.  People tend to help more when they see what you've done and can understand how they can help.

Comment: Related & perhaps useful post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655393/visualizing-a-toroidal-surface-in-matlab